# Como posicionar este Texto abaixo da Tabela?

Tags: latex

Usando este código LaTeX:

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{UC-Responder Atividade}}                                                                                                                                                                              \\ \hline
\textbf{Objetivo}        & \textbf{Permitir que o usuário responda as atividades criadas.}                                                                                                                                         \\ \hline
\textbf{Requisitos}      & \textbf{Estar participando de grupo .}                                                                                                                                                                  \\ \hline
\textbf{Atores}          & \textbf{Aluno.}                                                                                                                                                                                         \\ \hline
\textbf{Pré-Condições}   & \textbf{Estar presente em um grupo.}                                                                                                                                                                    \\ \hline
\textbf{Fluxo Principal} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}A) O usuário clica sobre o nome da atividade.\\ B) O usuário responde a atividade.\\ C) O usuário clica no botão (enviar).\\ D) Caso de Uso encerrado.\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Pós-Condições}   & \textbf{Atividade respondida e cadastrada}                                                                                                                                                              \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Mas sempre fica uma parte do texto abaixo da tabela, onde este texto deveria ficar abaixo de todas as tabelas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como consigo resolver este problema?

Comment: Favor ler [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas) e editar a pergunta com o código na formatação correta e não como imagem. Isso ajuda a pergunta a ser respondida.

Comment: Adicione o LaTeX à pergunta para facilitar a resposta.

Comment: @Tony código inserido .

Comment: Que texto? Seria a legenda?

Comment: @Tony  Tenho o referencial teórico que deveria ficar abaixo de todas as tabelas.As tabelas estão ficando entre o texto do referencial já usei a o comando \newpage e não deu certo.Tem de haver um comando que 'empurre'  o texto abaixo da tabela para a próxima pagina.

Comment: Quando fica 3 tabelas em uma pagina o texto é empurrado para a próxima pagina .Mas quando tenho apenas 2 fica desta forma na imagem.

Comment: Adicionei mais uma imagem

Comment: @Tony resolvi o problema com o comando \clearpage

Comment: Muito bem! Se quiser, poderá colocar a resposta como você fez, para ajudar quem tiver a mesmo problema.

Answer (score 0):

Se o que vem depois da tabela são as referência, talvez funcione colocar `\newpage`. Esse tipo de erro é muito comum e em todas as minhas experiências anteriores eu mudava os termos para localização, exemplo:

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\end{table}

\newpage
\begin{table}[h]
\end{table}
```

e etc.